# I can't read the client selection when i set it to an object from the mongo schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

`getting the client inputs`

```
// getting the request body
const username = req.body.username;
const _userRole = req.body.userRole;
const password = req.body.password;
const password2 = req.body.password2;
```

`setting the req body to an object that created from the schema userDB`

console.log(_userRole);

```
let newUser = new userDB({
    username: username, // first is the attribute NAME of the model , second is the name value tag in the html file
    userRole: _userRole,
    password: password
});

console.log(newUser.userRole);
```

`Error`

the first line which it's admin refers to this code `console.log(_userRole);` 
once i put set it to an object inside the new object i get undefined as u can see in the error    `console.log(newUser.userRole);`

```
    admin
undefined
Error: userSchema validation failed: usersRoles: Path `usersRoles` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:48:26)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:745:19)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:319:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (internal/util/inspect.js:1979:40)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1861:10)
    at console.value (internal/console/constructor.js:327:14)
    at console.log (internal/console/constructor.js:363:61)
    at E:\HalalMunchies\server\controller\usersController.js:105:33
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  errors: {
    usersRoles: ValidatorError: Path `usersRoles` is required.
        at validate (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1277:13)
        at E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1260:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at ObjectId.SchemaType.doValidate (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1210:14)
        at E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2690:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'usersRoles',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'userSchema validation failed'
}
```

`the schemas`

`UserSchema`

```
    //requiring the mongoose module 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// create the schema 
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    //creating the attributes/ data of the schema

    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    usersRoles: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'usersRolesSchema',
        required: true
    }

});



const userDB = mongoose.model('userSchema', userSchema);

module.exports = userDB;
```

`UserRole Schema`

```
    //requiring the mongoose module 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');



var usersRolesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    userRole: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

})

const userRolesModel = mongoose.model('usersRolesSchema', usersRolesSchema);

module.exports = userRolesModel;
```

Comment: You have a typo: `user` property called `usersRoles` but you try to set `userRole` in your record.

Comment: @Xeelley so the property `userRole` in `usersRolesSchema ` has to be the same like this `usersRole` in `userSchema `.

Comment: No, it hasn't. You define `usersRoles` in your `userSchema`, so any user instance/record should match this schema, it means you can pass to new record exactly same structure: `let newUser = new userDB({ ..., userRoles: value })`